# Unity - instantiate objects in a loop with spacing between each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I generate a grid of cubes by 10x10. My cells are different, I choose them out of an array.

What I need is a small spacing between each cell.

This is my code so far

```
private void Start()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < data.MapSize.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < data.MapSize.y; y++)
        {
            Instantiate(data.Cells[Random.Range(0, data.Cells.Length)]), new Vector3(x, 0, z), Quaternion.identity); // Create a specific cell on position (x,y)
        }
    }
}
```

So what I've tried out:

```
new Vector3(x + 1, 0, z + 1)

new Vector3(x * 0.1f, 0, z * 0.1f)
```

but obviously it won't change anything.

So I tried out this:

Before the start method I created a variable

```
int counter = 0;
```

and within the loops

```
counter += 0.1f;
new Vector3(x + counter, 0, z + counter)
```

but then there appears no grid, I get an parallelogram.

Comment: Don't increment counter if you want consistent spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define your spacing length, so you can easily change it later.

```
float spacing = 0.1f;
```

Then use this to get the desired result.

```
Instantiate(data.Cells[Random.Range(0, data.Cells.Length)]), new Vector3(x + (x*spacing), 0, y + (y*spacing)), Quaternion.identity); // Create a specific cell on position (x,y)
```

Notice I changed `z` to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on whether or not you want your grid to remain exactly 10 units across, in world space.

If the size of the grid doesn't matter, you can just add the padding to your x and y increments (and use a floating point instead of integer). You will also have to increase data.MapSize to take into account the padding:

```
for (float x = 0; x < data.MapSize.x; x += 1.1f)
{
    for (float y = 0; y < data.MapSize.y; y += 1.1f)
    {
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider scaling down the objects that you're storing in data.Cells in order to create the space without affecting the grid size. You could either scale down the prefab, or do it as they're being instantiated:

```
GameObject newCell = (GameObject)Instantiate(data.Cells[Random.Range(0, data.Cells.Length)]), new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity); // Create a specific cell on position (x,y)
newCell.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
```

Edit: Lestat's solution is a cleaner version of the first option, so if the final size of the grid doesn't matter then I would go with that instead of modifying the x and y variables.